# Ipad resolution for landscape and portrait - Xamarin ios

Tags: c#, iphone, ipad, xamarin.ios, screen-resolution

> I am relatively new to Xamarin ios and am creating an application that
>   will work in both Landscape and Portrait for both iPhone and iPad.

I have been able to implement both Landscape and portrait on iPhone pretty fine by using a rotation callback method that will invoke a different view with the same layout but adjusted dimensions for the landscape version and on the landscape version I have the same to go back to portrait. This works okay but has some lag at times.

I'm not very sure about what is the right way to present two different UIs for different orientations. If anyone has any suggestions please let me know.

Now I have a list that holds values for Height and Width of the current device and I will devise this by the current device density like so:

maindisplayinfo.height / maindisplayinfo.density

and this gives me the current display dimensions I need. I use this to place my objects relative to a screen portion such as:

```
CGRect(0, Height * 0.30, Image.Bounds.Width, Image.Bounds.Height)
```

On rotation on Ipad, the display goes funny even though I have set dimensions correctly and my rotation callback triggers the different views. Not sure what is going on here.

But is there a certain way to do this sort of thing with iPad and iPhone?

Comment: "display goes funny" is not a helpful description of the problem.  Can you post a screenshot illustrating the "correct" vs "funny" view?

Comment: I can’t sorry. As I am not legally allowed to show the code. Basically though the view takes up half the screen on the iPad and doesn’t adjust to the right height either as the bottom of the view is off to the bottom and doesn’t show. I think I have figured the issue and can use Xamarin Essentials to trigger an event when the device is rotated to display the correct view.

Comment: You can have two different UIs when the device rotated. And I recommend you to use [autoLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/programmatic-layout-constraints) to layout your views. If you find a solution, you can write it in the answer and mark it which can help more people with same problem:).